# Firebase Database rules data.child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I cannot seem to get a read to work as I need it to. Basically, I want a user to read if they are the author, OR read if they are an admin (set by me).

After a write, my DB looks as such:

```
master
--messages
----<some message id>
      admin: true
      name: "My name"
      text: "Message test"
      uid: <proper firebase auth uid>
```

My rules:

```
{
"rules": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".read": "auth != null && (data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid || data.child('admin').val() === true)",
  }
}
```

I've run it through the simulator numerous times and manners, yet read is always a fail. I'm wondering if my data.children vars aren't containing what I expect them to have, but I can't find a way to log that.

Any insight?

Edit: screenshots... Er, I don't have the rep to post images. This is the url.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwcfP.jpg

Comment: In case more clarity is required: This is based on a chat app where I may have 10 users talking, but each user will see ONLY what they have typed unless they are the admin. I will still need to have the admins replies targeted to the appropriate user, but I feel confident I can accomplish that aspect.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of your simulator that includes the path you're reading, the JSON at that path, and the auth state that you use.